# Moving a plunker project to jsonstub.com

Tags: plunker

I created a test project in plunker that uses various filters to display different results from an archive of recipes. Initially I was instructed to create the archive in my js file and work solely with Angularjs. For the next part of my test I have been instructed to move that archive to jsonstub.com

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm still learning. How would I go about doing this? I cant seem to find any tutorials or similar questions.

Comment: This is not really an Angular or JSON question.

Comment: @itamar apologies. those tags have been removed. do you have any solutions to my problem though?